# Define CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN in PHP?

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, drush, aegir

Is it possible to use PHP to define the CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN setting located in civicrm.settings.php? We are using Drupal.

I have successfully used the following to change some settings before:

`Civi::settings()->set('customPHPPathDir', "$root/CustomPHP/");`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a setting you can set with Civi::settings. You can set it with a define() anywhere outside of civicrm.settings.php, but it would need to run that section in your file before running the code where it gets used, so somewhere pretty early in a page run. It always falls back to CIVICRM_DSN if CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN is not set, if your setting runs too late.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. Would it need to get called every single time before civicrm.settings.php (before a Civi page is even starting to load)? If that is the case, maybe a drupal hook would work?

Comment: Yes that might work if the drupal module has a higher weight than the civicrm module (e.g. the weight field in the drupal system table in drupal 7).

Comment: I mean lower weight, oops. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-update-a-modules-weight